# What is the right way to sort a linked list in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I have this linked list:

```
class Node {
    Node next;
    int num;

    public Node(int val) {
        num = val;
        next = null;
    }
}

public class LinkedList {

    Node head;

    public LinkedList(int val) {
        head = new Node(val);
    }

    public void append(int val) {
        Node tmpNode = head;
        while (tmpNode.next != null) {
            tmpNode = tmpNode.next;
        }
        tmpNode.next = new Node(val);
    }
    public void print() {
        Node tmpNode = head;
        while (tmpNode != null) {
            System.out.print(tmpNode.num + " -> ");
            tmpNode = tmpNode.next;
        }
        System.out.print("null");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList myList = new LinkedList(8);
        myList.append(7);
        myList.append(16);
        myList.print();
    }
}
```

and I want to know how should I sort this linked list? I tried to sort it but strange numbers starts comming out and in other cases it do nothing and sort nothing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the linked list sorted while insert itself. So that you dont need another function to sort it. You didn't consider the initial scenario where the head will be null only that is the error

```
public void insert(int val) {
Node currentNode = head;
Node nextNode = head.next;

if (head==null) {
    head = new Node(val);
    head.next = null;
    return;
}

if (currentNode.num > val) {
    Node tmpNode = head;
    head = new Node(val);
    head.next = tmpNode;
    return;
}

if (nextNode != null && nextNode.num > val) {
    currentNode.next = new Node(val);
    currentNode.next.next = nextNode;
    return;
}

while (nextNode != null && nextNode.num < val) {
    currentNode = nextNode;
    nextNode = nextNode.next;
}

currentNode.next = new Node(val);
currentNode.next.next = nextNode;
}
```

Comment: that's not what o want ... i only want a sort method without insert

Comment: then you should update the exact requirement in the question, so that others wont get confused with your question